# Why does (int)[@"-1" floatValue] does not return -1

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsstring

I tested this expression in gdb:

```
(gdb) p (int)[@"-1" floatValue]
$2 = 1
```

but

```
(gdb) p (int)((float)[@"-1" floatValue])
$7 = -1
```

comes out as I expect

Why does the first expression not return `-1`? Also, what is the return type of `[@"-1" floatValue]`?

Comment: I write some code to test the result 
    int d = [@"-1" floatValue];
    float f = [@"-1" floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%d,  %f", d, f);
the result is both -1, it is right. so it is the issue of gdb to treat with the value of [@"-1" floatValue];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gdb doesn't know the return type of methods (or functions):

```
(gdb) p [@"-1" floatValue]
Unable to call function "objc_msgSend" at 0x155d08c: no return type information available.
To call this function anyway, you can cast the return type explicitly (e.g. 'print (float) fabs (3.0)')
```

When you cast the expression to `int`, gdb assumes that the method returns an `int`.  So it knows it can use [`objc_msgSend`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_msgSend) to send the message and treat the return value from `objc_msgSend` as an `int`.

When you cast the expression to a `float`, gdb assumes that the method returns a `float`.  So it knows that it should use [`objc_msgSend_fpret`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW50) to send the message and treat the return value as a float.

This is important because:

> On the i386 platform, the ABI for functions returning a floating-point
>   value is incompatible with that for functions returning an integral
>   type. On the i386 platform, therefore, you must use objc_msgSend_fpret
>   for functions that for functions [sic] returning non-integral type.

Comment: I have no idea if this is right but it at least _sounds_ intelligent and convincing :-)